# Auto Escaping Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, escaping

In an Asp.net Mvc application all string output is unescaped by default either you remember to escape everything with HTTPUtility or you open yourself up to XSS attacks.

Now I'm a forgetful guy so I'm looking for a solution that helps me "not forget" to escape all my strings for me.

Can anybody share any techniques they've used make escaping all Asp.net MVC output easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jfar, what you want is absolute possible, see this excellent blog post:

http://blog.codeville.net/2007/12/19/aspnet-mvc-prevent-xss-with-automatic-html-encoding/

**Steve Sanderson** explains step-by-step how to change "<%=....>" behavior, overriding GenerateCodeFromStatement() method from CSharpCodeProvider class, that is a cool thing. cleans up a lot of HttpUtility.HtmlEncode calls and works pretty well with asp.net mvc.

Comment: From what I've read this seems like the best option until ASP.NET 4.0 comes out with the new <%: x %> syntax. See this link:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that a lot of things aren't "built-in" to MVC, because that's sorta one of the core values of it: it's flexible enough to give you a lot of control, and therefore it expects you to do some things yourself.

However, check out [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.org), specifically FluentHtml; I believe it does encoding for you by default.